# How/When does the server get to know that a connection got staled?

Tags: java, websphere, connection-pooling

As per IBM documentation:
Purge Policy
Specifies how to purge connections when a stale connection or fatal connection error is detected.
Valid values are EntirePool and FailingConnectionOnly.

Question:
How/When does the server get to know that a connection got staled? Does it purge the pool as soon as (immediately?) any connection goes stale or it happens as per the reap time?

Say if the reap time is 180 seconds. Let's say the reap thread last ran at 3:05 PM and a connection goes stale at 3:06 PM, will the server purge the pool at 3:06 PM itself or the purge will happen only at 3:08 PM ? Is there a risk of clients getting staled connection objects between 3:06 and 3:08 ?

The IBM document i'm referring to is:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzamy/50/admin/help/udat_conpoolset.html

Answer (score 1):

Stale connections are identified in the following ways:

1. JDBC operation is performed that raises SQLRecoverableException or SQLNonTransientConnectionException, or a general SQLException with a SQL State or error code that the application server has built-in knowledge of. For specific lists of SQL states and error codes, refer to the SQLState mappings in [DatabaseHelper](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.jdbc/src/com/ibm/ws/rsadapter/impl/DatabaseHelper.java) and its various subclasses per database.
2. JDBC driver's ConnectionEventListener.connectionErrorOccurred signals the application server that a connection has gone bad.

When the application server learns that a connection has gone bad, it does not return that connection to the pool. Subsequent requests outside of the sharing scope would never get that same connection.

Purge Policy determines what the application server does with the other connections that are in the pool at the time that a stale connection occurred.  The application server can aggressively purge all connections from the pool (EntirePool option), or it can leave the others there (FailingConnectionOnly option), or it can check all connections in the pool before allowing them to be handed out (ValidateAllConnections option).

Note that the property values above are for WebSphere Application Server Liberty.  If using traditional, ValidateAllConnections is done as the combination of FailingConectionOnly plus defaultPretestOptimizationOverride=true.